# Curve guide on linked object

Tags: physics, linked-data, particles

I am linking in a rigged character to another file. But I cannot seem to get the "Curve Guide" physics to work for the hair of the character.

Some bones of the rig controls some empties that in turn works as hooks on a curve. 
Finally, the curve is enabled as a "Curve Guide" which controls the movement of a hair braid.

The problem is that the curve guide does not seem to be working when I link in the character in another file. I have made the rig a proxy and I see changes in the curve placement when I move the bones, but the hair is unaffected by the the curve guide.

Is there a way to get this to work? Preferably without making local copies of things.

Note: In the character file everything work as intended. It is when I link the group containing the character, the rig, the empties and the hair emitter that I run into problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Particle systems can't be linked into a scene dynamically. So you can't change the shape of the hair from what it is in the original file. You'll have to append the emitter as a local object.

An alternative, for braided hair that could work well, is to model the braids as a mesh object with either particles wrapped around it or a texture. Then use the curve guides+hooks+armature proxy system to animate that.